# Cumulative distribution function of $X1_{X>c}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> I want to find the CDF of $Y=X1_{X>c}$. Using some of my knowledge I have found it to be $$P(Y<y)=P(X>c)P(X<y)+P(X<c)$$ where $c$ is some positive constant. The random variable $X$ is defined only for positive values. I want to know whether my expression for $P(Y<y)$ is right or wrong? Please correct me if my expression is wrong.

**My Attempt**:

\begin{align}&P(Y<y)=P(X1_{X>c}<y)=\\[0.2cm]&=P(\mathbf 1_{X>c}=1)P\left(X<\frac{y}{\mathbf 1_{X>c}}\middle |\: \mathbf 1_{X>c}=1\right)+P(\mathbf 1_{X>c}=0)P\left(X<\frac{y}{\mathbf 1_{X>c}}\middle |\: \mathbf 1_{X>c}=0\right) \\[0.2cm]&=P(c<X<y)+P\left(\mathbf 1_{X>c}=0\right)P(X<\infty)\end{align}

Comment: So, the last line simplifies even more to $$P(c<X<y)+P(X<c)=\begin{cases}P(X<y), & \text{if } c\le y \\ P(X<c), &\text{ if } y<c\end{cases}$$ For $y\le 0$, $F_Y(y)=0$ (you already new this) which completes the proof. I think this is correct now! However, I assumed that $P(X=\infty)=0$ however for this simplification.

Comment: @JimmyR. good help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First write down $Y$ explicitly $$Y=X\mathbf 1_{X>c}=\begin{cases}0, &\text{ if }X\le c\\X, &\text{ if } X>c\end{cases}$$
So, the value of $Y$ depends on the value of $X$ and hence when calculating a probability about $Y$ you should take cases based on the value of $X$. For the CDF (which I define with $\le$ instead of $<$ as in your post) we need only to consider values of $y>0$ since $X>0$ and hence $F_Y(y)=0$ for $y\le 0.$ So, for $y>0$ you have

\begin{align}F_Y(y)&=P(Y\le y)=P(X\mathbf 1_{X>c}\le y)\\[0.3cm]&=P(0\le y\mid X\le c)P(X\le c)+P(X\le y\mid X>c)P(X>c)\\[0.2cm]&=P(0\le y)P(X\le c)+\frac{P(c<X\le y)}{P(X>c)}P(X>c)\\[0.2cm]&=1\cdot P(X\le c)+P(c<X\le y)\\[0.2cm]&=P(X\le c)+P(c<X\le y)\end{align}

Now, the second summand is equal to zero if $0<y\le c$ which gives $$F_Y(y)=P(X\le c)+0, \qquad 0<y\le c$$ Contrary, if $y>c$, then you may add the probabilites to get $$F_Y(y)=P(X\le c)+P(c<X\le y)=P(X\le y), \qquad y>c$$ Putting these together, you get \begin{align}F_Y(y)=\begin{cases}0,&\text{if }y\le 0 \\F_X(c),& \text{if }0<y\le c \\F_X(y),& \text{if }c<y\end{cases}\end{align} This shows that $Y$ has an atom at $y=0$, i.e. $P(Y=0)>0$.

Comment: How does the first summand becomes $1$? Should it not be $P(X\leq c)$. Further, it seems your answer and Ian answer differ? Can you comment on this difference? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant that $P(0\le y)=1$ so the first summand becomes $1\cdot P(X\le c)=P(X\le c)$. It was a mistake. I think now they give the same result.

Comment: No, they do not give the same result, since I do not agree with Ian at the following: $$P(Y\le y \mid X>c)=P(X\le y \mid X>c)=\frac{P(c<X\le y)}{P(X>c)}\neq P(X\le y)$$ as Ian suggests.

Comment: So you think his answer is different from yours? i get this feeling because I think the expressions look different

Comment: If his answer is incorrect according to you then mine will also be incorrect?  Please comment whether my and Ian answers are incorrect or correct?

Comment: @Ian 's assertion is false according to the following thinking: Let as an example $c=5$ and $y=1$ and assume as you have it that $P(0<X\le 1)>0$. Then Ian asserts that $$P(Y\le 1 \mid X>5)=P(X\le 1)>0$$ which is not true, since we know that in this case $Y=X>5$ and hence $P(Y\le 1 \mid X>5)=0$. Am I wrong? What do you think? Perhaps I am confusing something.

Comment: I do not know about your example but I think the expression $\frac{P(c<X\leq y)}{P(X>c)}$ is not equal to $P(X\leq y)$. And if Ian has asserted this then I think he is right

Comment: No, I assert that $$P(Y\le y \mid X>c)=\frac{P(c<X\le y)}{P(X>c)}$$ and @Ian asserts that $$P(Y\le y \mid X>c)=P(X\le y)$$ I put the not equal sign to show that we assert different things. What do you think?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46740/discussion-between-frank-moses-and-jimmy-r).

Comment: I added my attempt on my post. What do you think where is the error in my approach?
I think my answer is much similar to Ian answer

Comment: I see my mistake now. When $X>c$ you have $Y=X$ but that means that $P(Y \leq y \mid X>c)=P(X \leq y \mid X>c)$ which is not simply $P(X \leq y)$. Let me correct it.

Comment: Many Thanks Jimmy for your help. I understand too where was the problem.

Comment: I think my attempt is right too because in the third step of my attempt I assumed $y$ to be nonnegtive (thats why its $\infty$)

Comment: @FrankMoses No, I think there are is a flaw in the (now) second line $$P(X<\frac{y}{1_{X>c}}\mid 1_{X=c}=1)=P(X<y\mid X>c)$$ but you find in your second line that this is equal to $P(X<y)$ which is not the same.The second with $\infty$ came out ok.

Comment: @FrankMoses Now, after your edit, it seems correct to me! Good job!! (more compact than mine)!!!

Answer (score 4):

The CDF would be

$$P(Y \leq y)=P(Y \leq y \mid X \leq c)P(X \leq c)+P(Y \leq y \mid X>c)P(X>c).$$

Now you're left to evaluate the conditional probabilities:

- For $P(Y \leq y \mid X>c)$, we notice that when $X>c$ we have $Y=X$. Thus $P(Y \leq y \mid X>c)=P(X \leq y \mid X>c)=\frac{P(c<X \leq y)}{P(X>c)}$. This will be $0$ if $y \leq c$, otherwise it will be $\frac{P(X \leq y)-P(X \leq c)}{P(X>c)}$.
- If $X \leq c$ then $Y=0$, so $P(Y \leq y \mid X \leq c)=1$ if $y \geq 0$ and $0$ otherwise.

You can now substitute in to finish the problem.

Comment: Wow thats excellent help. This is the very reason I ask questions at this forum because sometimes the most easiest looking problems (to me) have serious issues.BTW many thanks for your help.

Comment: I assumed that $X$ only has positive values thats why I did not consider the case of $y<0$ because this event has zero probability.

Comment: Sure. But strictly speaking this information is part of the CDF of $Y $, even if it is not very interesting.

Comment: There has been some confusion in your answer and Jimmy R. answer. Please comment how to solve this confusion. Many thanks in advance.